# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object()

Tags: php, mysqli

código funciona se for com o fetch() com o fetch_object() da o erro

```
public function consulta($id) {

  $mysqli = $this->conexao->getCon();
      $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE id_pessoa = ?");
      $sql->bind_param("s", $id);
      $sql->execute();
      $sql->store_result();
      //asim funciona
      $sql->bind_result($id_pessoa, $nome, $nascimento, $naturalidade, $nacionalidade, $sexo, $altura, $tipo, $cpf, $rg, $alcunha, $cutis_id, $civil_id, $status_id, $pront, $carac, $att, $user_id);
      $sql->fetch();

      return $nome;

      /* assim não funciona e aparece o erro
      $obj = new Alvo();
      $obj = $sql->fetch_object();
      return $obj->nome;
      */
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu seu problema? Existe alguma dúvida pendente? Se a dúvida estiver solucionada, considere aceitar a resposta. Veja mais detalhes em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/100416)

Answer (score 1):

Conforme [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php), a assinatura do método é `mysqli_result::fetch_object`. Ou seja, ele deve ser executado no resultado da query, não na query em si.

Por exemplo:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    $obj = $result->fetch_object();
    $result->close();
}
```